# amblone error :85: error: 'TCCR3B' was not declared in this scope - no fullscreen vlc support

Tags: arduino-uno

getting the following error when trying to upload Amblone code to my Arduino One board:

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\pha\Desktop\amblone\amblone.pde: In function 'void setup()':

amblone:85: error: 'TCCR3B' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR3B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x2;

   ^

amblone:86: error: 'TCCR4B' was not declared in this scope

   TCCR4B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x2;

   ^

exit status 1
'TCCR3B' was not declared in this scope

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe1
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Code:

```
void setup()   {                
  // initialize the serial communication
  Serial.begin(256000); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 256000 bps

  TCCR0B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x2;
  TCCR1B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x2;
  TCCR2B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x2;
  TCCR3B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x2;
  TCCR4B = TCCR0B & 0b11111000 | 0x2;

  State = S_WAIT_FOR_SF;
}
```

Comment: The full code please.

Answer (score 1):

Amblone doesn't work on an Uno. As stated in the requirements list, you require a Mega.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Majenko, I realised I was uploading code to wrong arduino board as mine was Mega not Uno.

I was also not getting colour changes (Amblone) when playing a file on VLC player full screen - downgraded version and it works again now.